# Is it possible to count number of ICMP packets sent/received per interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, interface, statistics, icmp, packets

Is it possible to check statistics in Linux per interface for ICMP packets in particular? **ifconfig** command it provides statistics per interface for received and sent packets:

```
-> /sbin/ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BC:30:5B:ED:DE:54  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:412327300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:765211747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:327931865613 (312740.1 Mb)  TX bytes:803392590272 (766174.8 Mb)
          Memory:dcc00000-dcd00000
```

But what I am looking for, is some specific type of packets (like ICMP) per interface.

Also Linux is providing those statistics but globally in **/proc/net/snmp**:

```
-> cat /proc/net/snmp
... log truncated ...
Icmp: InMsgs InErrors InDestUnreachs InTimeExcds InParmProbs InSrcQuenchs InRedirects InEchos InEchoReps InTimestamps InTimestampReps InAddrMasks InAddrMaskReps OutMsgs OutErrors OutDestUnreachs OutTimeExcds OutParmProbs OutSrcQuenchs OutRedirects OutEchos OutEchoReps OutTimestamps OutTimestampReps OutAddrMasks OutAddrMaskReps
Icmp: 29697 5 276 9 0 0 0 29409 3 0 0 0 0 29970 0 561 0 0 0 0 5 29404 0 0 0 0
IcmpMsg: InType0 InType3 InType8 InType11 OutType0 OutType3 OutType8
IcmpMsg: 3 276 29409 9 29404 561 5
... log truncated ...
```

Or more pretty printing in with **netstat -s** command (-s stands for statistics of course):

```
-> netstat -s
... log truncated ...
Icmp:
    29697 ICMP messages received
    5 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 276
        timeout in transit: 9
        echo requests: 29409
        echo replies: 3
    29970 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 561
        echo request: 5
        echo replies: 29404
IcmpMsg:
        InType0: 3
        InType3: 276
        InType8: 29409
        InType11: 9
        OutType0: 29404
        OutType3: 561
        OutType8: 5
... log truncated ...
```

So, the question is. is there any way to get ICMP statistics for some specific interface instead of global ICMP statistics for the whole system in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the kernel keeps counters for each protocol per interface. Taking a look into code which feeds `/proc/net/netstat` (among other things) we can find plenty of references to `rtnl_link_stats64` which is defined in `include/uapi/linux/if_link.h`:

```
/* The main device statistics structure */
struct rtnl_link_stats64 {
        __u64   rx_packets;             /* total packets received       */
        __u64   tx_packets;             /* total packets transmitted    */
        __u64   rx_bytes;               /* total bytes received         */
        __u64   tx_bytes;               /* total bytes transmitted      */
        __u64   rx_errors;              /* bad packets received         */
        __u64   tx_errors;              /* packet transmit problems     */
        __u64   rx_dropped;             /* no space in linux buffers    */
        __u64   tx_dropped;             /* no space available in linux  */
        __u64   multicast;              /* multicast packets received   */
        __u64   collisions;

        /* detailed rx_errors: */
        __u64   rx_length_errors;
        __u64   rx_over_errors;         /* receiver ring buff overflow  */
        __u64   rx_crc_errors;          /* recved pkt with crc error    */
        __u64   rx_frame_errors;        /* recv'd frame alignment error */
        __u64   rx_fifo_errors;         /* recv'r fifo overrun          */
        __u64   rx_missed_errors;       /* receiver missed packet       */

        /* detailed tx_errors */
        __u64   tx_aborted_errors;
        __u64   tx_carrier_errors;
        __u64   tx_fifo_errors;
        __u64   tx_heartbeat_errors;
        __u64   tx_window_errors;

        /* for cslip etc */
        __u64   rx_compressed;
        __u64   tx_compressed;
};
```

If I got it right this is the structure in which per-link (or per-interface which comes semantically being the same thing in this case) statistics are kept and there don't seem to be protocol specific counters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in fact I also double checked the implementation itself (updated my question) and it seems you are completely right with your answer.

Comment: In fact the statistics you pointed can be retrieved in /sys/class/net/<interface>/statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation itself when it increases the counters and it seems Linux is not providing these stats per interface for specific protocols as you mention:

```
struct icmp_mib icmp_statistics;

...

static void icmp_out_count(int type)

{

        if(type>18)

               return;

        (*icmp_pointers[type].output)++;

        icmp_statistics.IcmpOutMsgs++;

}

...

int icmp_rcv(struct sk_buff *skb, struct device *dev, struct options *opt,

         __u32 daddr, unsigned short len,

         __u32 saddr, int redo, struct inet_protocol *protocol)

{
...
icmp_statistics.IcmpInMsgs++;
        if(len < sizeof(struct icmphdr))

        {

               icmp_statistics.IcmpInErrors++;
        ...
        }
...
}
```

And so on. So it seems general statistics for all interfaces, never mention specific interfaces.